# How do I install gcc from Kubuntu USB

Tags: usb, kubuntu, gcc

My laptop has a slightly obscure wifi card and I can't install a driver from the driver management or the USB, and I don't have ethernet. Instead, I found a driver online and it worked on a Live USB because I could install gcc from the USB. However, when I actually installed the OS, I could not start the driver or install gcc!

So, how do I install gcc from a USB or ISO in Kubuntu 15.10.

EDIT:

Another solution I'm open to is to download the packages outside of Kubuntu and then use dpkg -i to install them. In that case I would need someone to list the needed packages and where to download them.

Comment: GCC is installed by default. Are you sure it's GCC you're missing, or some dependency?

Comment: Yes, I am absolutely sure gcc is missing. I've tried "gcc --version" and it says I need to install it.

Comment: What happens when you try to install `gcc`? For example, you could post the output of `sudo apt-get install gcc`

Comment: When I try to install gcc, the terminal spits out a bunch of "failed to fetch blahblahblah.com" and stuff like that. The problem is that I don't have internet to install gcc.

Comment: Related: [How can I install software or packages without Internet (offline)?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! Here are the steps I took.

First I booted into the Live USB, because I knew I could get gcc there, and then I used "apt-get download gcc gcc-5 etc.." to grab the .deb files from the USB. Then I moved them into a folder on my Kubuntu installation. Finally, I was able to use "dpkg -i *.deb" to install all of the packages.

I wrote this answer on my, now wified, Kubuntu installation.